# Sonarqube 5.0 install error

Tags: sonarqube

When installing sonarqube 5.0, I got following error messages while starting SonarQube on windows7 with mysql 5.6.22:

```
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
2015.01.19 11:18:57 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: C:\Tools\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Tools\sonarqube-5.0\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer C:\Users\li2\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-process2755720839215931323properties
2015.01.19 11:19:09 INFO  sea[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
2015.01.19 11:19:09 INFO  sea[o.s.s.SearchServer]  Starting Elasticsearch[sonarqube] on port 9001
2015.01.19 11:19:09 WARN  sea[o.s.s.SearchSettings]  Elasticsearch HTTP connector is enabled on port 9010. MUST NOT BE USED INTO PRODUCTION
2015.01.19 11:19:09 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1421662737113] version[1.1.2], pid[8464], build[e511f7b/2014-05-22T12:27:39Z]
2015.01.19 11:19:09 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1421662737113] initializing ...
2015.01.19 11:19:09 INFO  sea[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1421662737113] loaded [], sites []
2015.01.19 11:19:11 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1421662737113] initialized
2015.01.19 11:19:11 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1421662737113] starting ...
2015.01.19 11:19:27 INFO  sea[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1421662737113] bound_address {inet[/0.0.0.0:9001]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.0.107:9001]}
2015.01.19 11:19:30 INFO  sea[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1421662737113] new_master [sonar-1421662737113][RB8i_Ar8Rv-Do_15hhhWtQ][LI21][inet[/192.168.0.107:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1421662737113}, reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
2015.01.19 11:19:51 WARN  sea[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1421662737113] failed to connect to node [[sonar-1421662737113][RB8i_Ar8Rv-Do_15hhhWtQ][LI21][inet[/192.168.0.107:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1421662737113}]
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [sonar-1421662737113][inet[/192.168.0.107:9001]] connect_timeout[30s]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannels(NettyTransport.java:719) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:648) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:616) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:129) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:405) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:134) [elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information: /192.168.0.107:9001
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.connect(NioClientBoss.java:150) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientBoss.java:105) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:79) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
2015.01.19 11:19:51 INFO  sea[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1421662737113] sonarqube/RB8i_Ar8Rv-Do_15hhhWtQ
2015.01.19 11:19:51 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.http]  [sonar-1421662737113] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9010]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9010]}
2015.01.19 11:19:52 INFO  sea[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1421662737113] recovered [4] indices into cluster_state
2015.01.19 11:19:52 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1421662737113] started
2015.01.19 11:19:53 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[search] is up
2015.01.19 11:19:53 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: C:\Tools\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Tools\sonarqube-5.0\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;C:\Tools\sonarqube-5.0\lib\jdbc\mysql\mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\Users\li2\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-process1889452272417488373properties
2015.01.19 11:20:06 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting web
2015.01.19 11:20:06 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Connectors]  HTTP connector is enabled on port 9000
2015.01.19 11:20:06 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Webapp]  Webapp directory: C:\Tools\sonarqube-5.0\web
2015.01.19 11:20:07 INFO  web[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1421662737113] loaded [], sites []
2015.01.19 11:20:19 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl]  SonarQube Server / 5.0 / dc62506bf3b331ec19c053e225e415d164ee60b0
2015.01.19 11:20:19 INFO  web[o.s.c.p.Database]  Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
2015.01.19 11:20:20 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem]  SonarQube home: C:\Tools\sonarqube-5.0
2015.01.19 11:20:20 INFO  web[o.s.a.u.TimeProfiler]  Install plugins...
2015.01.19 11:20:20 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Findbugs / 3.1 / adc09c989cebc856d44239116a00ab0b602b0851
2015.01.19 11:20:20 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Duplications / 5.0 / dc62506bf3b331ec19c053e225e415d164ee60b0
2015.01.19 11:20:20 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Git / 5.0 / dc62506bf3b331ec19c053e225e415d164ee60b0
2015.01.19 11:20:20 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Core / 5.0 / dc62506bf3b331ec19c053e225e415d164ee60b0
2015.01.19 11:20:20 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Java / 2.8 / 20a3d682b1334eb1857e7bc8a40e11f04fed9528
2015.01.19 11:20:20 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin SVN / 5.0 / dc62506bf3b331ec19c053e225e415d164ee60b0
2015.01.19 11:20:20 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin English Pack / 5.0 / dc62506bf3b331ec19c053e225e415d164ee60b0
2015.01.19 11:20:20 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Email notifications / 5.0 / dc62506bf3b331ec19c053e225e415d164ee60b0
2015.01.19 11:20:20 INFO  web[o.s.a.u.TimeProfiler]  Install plugins done: 234 ms
2015.01.19 11:20:21 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer]  Deploy Ruby on Rails applications
2015.01.19 11:20:21 INFO  web[jruby.rack]  jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_71-b14 [Windows 7-amd64]
2015.01.19 11:20:21 INFO  web[jruby.rack]  using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2015.01.19 11:20:29 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  InitialSchema: migrating ==================================================
2015.01.19 11:20:29 INFO  web[DbMigration]  -- create_table(:projects, {})
2015.01.19 11:20:29 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0.0310s
2015.01.19 11:20:29 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
........
........
2015.01.19 11:20:50 INFO  web[o.s.j.s.AbstractDatabaseConnector]  Initializing Hibernate
2015.01.19 11:20:51 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient]  Update center: http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (HTTP proxy: xxx)
2015.01.19 11:20:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService]  Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
2015.01.19 11:20:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer]  Index rules for updates after Sun Jan 18 20:37:25 CET 2015
2015.01.19 11:20:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer]  Index activeRules for updates after Sun Jan 18 20:37:27 CET 2015
2015.01.19 11:20:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer]  Index sonarLogs for updates after null
2015.01.19 11:20:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer]  Index issues
2015.01.19 11:20:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer]  Index source files
2015.01.19 11:20:52 INFO  web[o.s.a.u.TimeProfiler]  Load metrics...
2015.01.19 11:20:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics]  Cleaning quality gate conditions
2015.01.19 11:20:52 INFO  web[o.s.a.u.TimeProfiler]  Load metrics done: 234 ms
2015.01.19 11:20:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDebtModel]  Register technical debt model...
2015.01.19 11:20:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDebtModel]  Register technical debt model done: 78 ms
2015.01.19 11:20:52 INFO  web[o.s.a.u.TimeProfiler]  Register rules...
2015.01.19 11:22:57 WARN  sea[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1421662737113] failed to reconnect to node [sonar-1421662737113][RB8i_Ar8Rv-Do_15hhhWtQ][LI21][inet[/192.168.0.107:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1421662737113}
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [sonar-1421662737113][inet[/192.168.0.107:9001]] connect_timeout[30s]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannels(NettyTransport.java:719) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:648) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:616) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:129) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$ReconnectToNodes.run(InternalClusterService.java:516) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information: /192.168.0.107:9001
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
```

I have searched for similar questions but with no success.
Does someone have an idea how to fix that?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you start from a fresh install ?

Comment: Hi Fabrice, thanks for your feedback. I do start from a fresh install.

Comment: Do you have any firewall (or similar software that controls which ports programs do open) installed on your Windows?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. It could be resolved by a possibility to not only specify `sonar.search.port` but also something like `sonar.search.host`. The reason in my setting is that the default IP which sonar search uses is only accessible from outside hosts. It must not be used from localhost.

I worked around it by adding the following line to sonar.properties as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28594063/1254572):

```
sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=-Des.network.host=127.0.0.1
```